# Using assemblies targeted for different .net framework version in the same application

Tags: .net

I have some assemblies that are targeted for .net framework 2.0, while some are targeted for .net framework 3.5. These assemblies are being invoked from an executable (winform app) which is targeted for .net framework 2.0.

I understand that the underlying CLR version for both the framework is 2.0 and there should not be any problem. However I need to understand on the consequences (if any) or things to watch out for.

Please share your experiences if there are any.

Comment: why do you use winform app with .Net 2.0 but not newer ?

Comment: To be precise, it is a legacy application and there is no much liberty of changing things.